# Switch statements that read integers from input and reacts accordingly

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a little task given to me which I am absolutely stumped on what to do.

The official brief is:

```
"Using switch, create a program that reads an integer from the keyboard and, 
indicate that the number is smaller than 1 and or smaller than 10, and or 
smaller than 100, and or smaller than 1000."
```

I've tried starting by typing `"int num = scanf("%d\n", &num);"`

and then doing the cases like follows

```
"case (num < 1 && <100): {

    printf("Excellent!!\n" );
    }"
```

But I am having no luck. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

EDIT:

Experimented with this but don't have any idea how I would get it to print Excellent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

int num;
scanf("%d\n", &num);

switch(num) {

case 1:
{
if(num < 1 && num < 10) {

    printf("Excellent!!\n" );
    }
}


}
}
```

Comment: To use a `switch` statement, you'll first need to count the digits in the number. To do that, repeatedly divide the number by 10 until it's zero, keeping a count of the number of divisions needed.

Comment: You will need to transform the requirements in the question into numbers 0,1,2,3 respectively (or otherwise) , not switch on `num` or use relational operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int num;
    int range = 0;

    printf("input num:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num < 1)
        range = -1;
    else {
        while(num /= 10){
            ++range;
        }
    }
    switch(range){
    case -1:
        puts("smaller than 1");
        break;
    case 0:
        puts("smaller than 10");
        break;
    case 1:
        puts("smaller than 100");
        break;
    case 2:
        puts("smaller than 1000");
        break;
    default:
        puts("More than 1000\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, from reading this I can now understand most of it. However could you please tell me what the else statement is declaring? (e.g the num /=10) part

Comment: @SkyPlus `num /= 10` meant `num = num / 10` E.g num = 99 ==> num /= 10 ==> num = 9, range = 1 ==> num /= 10 ==> num = 0, exit loop range = 1.

Comment: So wouldn't that mean that say num = 500 => num/=10 => num = 50, range = 1? Why would the range be 2? Also what happens to decimals say your 99 would be 9.9 not 9 right?

Comment: I think you need to consider that a number, say 57, is less than 100 **and** less than 1000. In the question it says _and/or_.

Comment: @SkyPlus num = 500 ==> num/=10, ==> num = 50, range = 1 ==> num/=10 == num = 5, range = 2 ==> num/=10 ==> num = 0, exit loop, range = 2. In `int`(positive) the division the fractional part of the result is discarded.

Comment: Ah I see, so it can only divide by a maximum of 2 times in its entirety unless its over 1000. So like num = 999 => num/=10 ==> num = 99, range = 1 ==> num/10 == num = 9, range =2 ==> num/10 ==> num = 0, range = 2?

Comment: Yes,  exactly !! (maximum 2 loop)

Answer (score 2):

```
int num = scanf("%d\n", &num);
```

This line is wrong. `scanf` doesn't return the number it just read; it returns the number of elements read successfully. So change it to

```
scanf("%d\n", &num);
```

As for the switch, the valid form is

```
switch (constant-integral-expression) {
    case one-label:
        actions
        break;
    case another-label:
        actions;
        break;
    default:
        actions if none of the above were satisfied
}
```

where the `default:` clause is optional. For example, if you want to count spaces, newlines, and tabs:

```
int c;
int nspace, nnl, ntab;

for (nspace = nnl = ntab = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ) {
    switch (c) {
        case ' ':
            ++nspace;
            break;
        case '\n':
            ++nnl;
            break;
        case '\t':
            ++ntab;
            break;
    }
}
printf("%d %d %d\n", nspace, nnl, ntab);
```

The actual program to write, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Edit: The `break` statement is crucial. Without the `break` statements at the end of each `case`, control would fall through to the next case. That is, the case statements following the first case would also be executed, and that can have undesired effects.

Comment: You probably need to mention the effect of `break;` statement inside the `case` block and the effect in its absence. It looks like the OP is heading toward that direction.

Comment: Is there a logical operator for and or? I dont know what my switch variable should be and what constitutes a case.

Comment: @SkyPlus - here's a hint. You need to calculate the number of digits. A single digit is definitely less than 10. A double digit is less than 100. a triple digit is less than 1000. However, all numbers less than 10 are also less than 100 and less than 1000. All numbers less than 100 are also less than 1000.

Comment: Thank you for the help, understand this now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { LESS_THAN_1, LESS_THAN_10, LESS_THAN_100, LESS_THAN_1000 };
    int a[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000 };

    int x;

    printf( "Enter a number: " );

    if ( scanf( "%d", &x ) == 1 )
    {
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) && !( x < a[i] ) ) ++i;

        switch ( i )
        {
        case LESS_THAN_1:
            printf( "x is smaller than %d\n", a[i] );
            break;
        case LESS_THAN_10:
            printf( "x is smaller than %d\n", a[i] );
            break;
        case LESS_THAN_100:
            printf( "x is smaller than %d\n", a[i] );
            break;
        case LESS_THAN_1000:
            printf( "x is smaller than %d\n", a[i] );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "x is greater than or equal to %d\n", a[i-1] );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```